# Register form validating, is the username already exist? (Java Web Application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, web-applications

> This is the format I need to use because this is a project for one of
>   my module. I already wrote validation for the form but I would like to
>   add another error message to the username. I want to show the user
>   when they type a username but that username would already in the DB it
>   would say the username already exist. (I am very beginner in
>   programming sry if my question is not clear.)

But Basically I just want to validate the username before they actually submit the form. My problem that I don't know how to search from this DB without submit the form.

Comment: There surly must be a better way to compose response body than to concatenate single string endlessly. :)

Comment: But I cannot change it this is the way I need to do the project.

Comment: Can't you maybe write your static html in a *.html file and load the content from it. That will at least allow you to have proper syntax highlighting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Spring? You can create a Spring controller and have the request mapping to be invoked by a jquery post method($.ajax). You should have a java script function that can be invoked when you shift focus from username field or when you hit submit as defined in your requirement. In the js method, have a $.ajax call to the spring controller which checks for user exists using a dao call. Using the spring controller response via ajax call you can validate before submitting the form.
You can also use java servlet instead of Spring controller. 
Refer Jquery post method. Use the java controller/servlet url within the $.ajax method.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});